# Can't get post ID using wp_insert_post_data

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, wp-insert-post

I have 3 custom fields as shown below. I want to use them to generate the title when I save/publish... etc

The code works if I insert the post id as a number but not like this...

```
function set_post_title( $data , $postarr ) {

    $title = "";
    $post_id = $postarr['ID'];     //NOT WORKING

    $last_name = get_post_meta($post_id, 'last-name', true);
    $middle_name = get_post_meta($post_id, 'middle-name', true);
    $first_name = get_post_meta($post_id, 'first-name', true);

//        $last_name = $data['last-name'];
//        $middle_name = $data['middle-name'];
//        $first_name = $data['first-name'];
//      also didn't work...

    if ( $last_name != "" ) {
        $title .= $last_name . ", ";
    }

    if ( !empty( $first_name ) ) {
        $title .= $first_name;
    }

    if ( !empty( $middle_name ) ) {
        $title .= " " . $middle_name;
    }

    $data['post_title'] = $title."aa".$post_id;

return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'set_post_title' );
```

If it would be easier I save my field values in another function using:

```
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'first-name', $_POST['first-name'] );
```

Is there something similar to update the title?

This has been driving me mad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data)

> You must pass 2 for the $accepted_args variable in add_filter() if you
>   want to access $postarr.

So use this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'set_post_title', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been going in circles. I actually removed that for some reason, thought it was optional... :)